# SQL group by multiple columns without aggregate functions

Tags: sql

How do I only find the `min` for `service_frequency` without the min for `quote_id`?

```
    SELECT *
FROM quotes QT
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT address_id, min(service_frequency) AS MINFrequency, min(quote_id) as quote_id
    FROM quotes
    GROUP BY address_id) groupQT
ON QT.address_id = groupQT.address_id
AND QT.quote_id = groupQT.quote_id
```

If `address_id` has multiple services with multiple service frequencies, I need to select the lowest frequency `min(service_frequency)` although without `AND QT.quote_id = groupQT.quote_id` will not match up properly.

Here is an unexpected output

| quote_id | service_frequency | address_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

Expected output:

| quote_id | service_frequency | address_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

It will match the correct `quote_id` to the lowest `service_frequency`. Instead of the lowest `service_frequency` with the lowest `quote_id`

I understand that SQL requires aggregate functions for *group by* although my statement requires that the value specified as removing the "On" will not work. It's been a long day, any help would be great.

SAMPLE DATA
[image]

Comment: Please add which RDBMS tag as well, that'd help

Comment: Also, can you provide sample data set of table `quotes`?